# Defining variable in strict mode

Tags: javascript, meteor, strict

I tried to use the strict mode for my meteor-app scripts. But using this code:

```
  "use strict";

  example = function(param) {
      var userId = Meteor.userId();
  }
```

gives me two linter errors:

```
  'Meteor' is not defined.
  'example' is not defined.
```

For the last one I think I have to define the function as

```
  const example = function() {}
```

**Update**:

But then linter gives me the error `example is defined, but never used`. I'm defining some functions in a separate file, so this function won't be used in this file.

And same problems for things like:

```
var month = parseInt(moment().format('MM'));
```

moment() is not defined...

Comment: What about `window.Meteor = Meteor` ? And then restrict strict mode to the function scopes?

Comment: But that would result in a horrible code, wouldn't it?

Comment: In my projects, I use the above approach, i.e., 'use strict' to function scope. Otherwise I wont be able to use any of the libraries.

Comment: Define meteor as a global for the linter.

Comment: This seems to be a point of frustration for several Meteor users. See [this github issues conversation in which a few workarounds and solutions are discussed](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1380).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The linter doesn't know about `Meteor` and `moment` because they are defined by other scripts.

How you deal with that depends on which linter you are using.

Putting `/* global Meteor, moment */` at the top of the script might resolve it.

Comment: Oh, didn't know that.

Comment: Please have a look at the updated post for the last question on that.